# MSSQL Select a parents ID value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Having some issues with a larger MSSQL DB I am administrating.
Have some functionallity I am trying to implement in a single table.

Table looks contains such columns:

```
ID              MailID
010-123456      12345678
010-123456/1    NULL
010-123456/2    NULL
010-123456/3    NULL
```

Now, what I would like to accomplish is to set each Childs MaildID to the same as its Parents MailID.

A ParentID being an ID with same value as the Child (Id ID row) before the "/" delimiter.
Also The IDs should not contins any chars, just digits (execpt for '-' and '/').

So currently I have this solution:

```
Declare @MyTable table(Child varchar(MAX),Parent varchar(MAX),ParentMaildId varchar(MAX))
insert into @MyTable
select ID as Child, left(ID, charindex('/', ID)-1) AS Parent, MailID as MailID
FROM [thisismy].[dbo].[table]
where ID not like '%[a-z]%' and  ID like '%/%' and MailId is not NULL

select * from @MyTable
--update t1
--SET t1.MailId = t2.ParentMaildId
--FROM [thisismy].[dbo].[table] AS t1
--INNER JOIN @IDAS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.Child
--WHERE t1.ID = t2.Child and t1.MailId is NULL
```

When I use the select statement to get MyTable fileld up here, it only returns a low subset of all the cases that is in my DB table, why?

I would like to have stored procedure that automatically updates the Mailid of the Child to the Parent (all recuired info being in the very same table).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you have a proper self-referencing foreign key? And can the ID really be 2Gb long, why does it need to be `varchar(max)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select m.*, p.mailid as imputed_parent
from @mytable m cross apply
     (select top (1) p.*
      from @mytable p
      where m.id like p.id + '/%'
      order by p.id desc
     ) p;
```

You can put this in an `update` using a correlated subquery:

```
update m
    set mailid = (select top (1) p.mailid
                  from @mytable p
                  where m.id like p.id + '/%'
                  order by p.id desc
                 )
    from @mytable m
    where m.mailid is null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=68f4b5bbfd8e8f06fd64b603820c3c87) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This does not work. It still gives me the same output as the solution I am currently using applied from the declared @mytable. Issue with current solution is that it does not select nearly all the entries FROM [thisismy].[dbo].[table]. The solution needs to find all parents MaildIDs given the childs ID in table [thisismy].[dbo].[table], and ofcourse if possible update them in the manner you showed here.

Comment: @AstralSailor . . . I added a db<>fiddle showing that it works for the question you asked here.  If your actual question is more complicated, you might want to ask a *new* question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Comment: Correct you are sir, I apologize. Using your example I was able to likely get it working. I however ran into: Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 26
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS" and "SQL_SwedishStd_Pref_CP1_CI_AS" in the like operation.

Completion time: 2021-07-16T14:56:08.1271035+02:00

Comment: @AstralSailor . . . I really have no idea what could be causing that problem.  Collations are not part of your question and it is hard for me to understand why the same table would have different collations in columns with similar information.